# Is there a language-agnostic way to do simple predicates in the parser?

Tags: antlr4

### Goal

I want to reduce (or eliminate) the Java-specific actions and predicates in my parser. Perhaps it isn't possible, but I wanted to ask here just in case there's some ANTLR4 feature I've missed. (The language itself is third-party, so I don't have control over that.)

### Simplified example

The predicates I want to use are mostly exact (or perhaps case-insensitive) string-matching. I *could* make big parallel sets of parser rules, but I'd rather not since the real-life example is considerably more convoluted.

Suppose I'm given something like:

```
isWidget(int) : "Whether it is a widget" : 4 ;
ownerFirstName(string) : "john" ;
ownerLastName(string) : "This is the last-name of the owner" : "doe" ;
```

I want the parser to look at the default-value (the last item on the line, like `4`, `"john"` or `"doe"`) and parse it based on the earlier type `(int)`, `(string)`, `(string)`.

```
main
    : stmt SEMIC (stmt SEMIC)* EOF 
    ;
stmt
    : propname=IDENTIFIER LPAREN datatype=IDENTIFIER RPAREN (COLON description=QUOTSTRING)? COLON df=defaultVal
    ;
defaultVal 
    : QUOTSTRING //TODO only this alt if datatype=string
    | NUM        //TODO only this alt if datatype=int
    ;

fragment Letter         :   'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ;
fragment Digit          :   '0'..'9'                ;   
fragment Underscore     :   '_'                     ;
SEMIC   : ';' ;
COLON   : ':' ;
LPAREN  : '(' ;
RPAREN  : ')' ;
IDENTIFIER : (Letter|Underscore) (Letter|Underscore|Digit)*      ;
QUOTSTRING : '"' ~('"' |'\n' | '\r' | '\u2029' | '\u2028')* '"'  ;
NUM : Digit+ ;
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

I know I can do it with predicates and rule inputs, but then I'm crossing the line from a language-agnostic grammar to one with embedded Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parser should handle things like the following without a problem:

```
isWidget(int) : "Whether it is a widget" : "foo" ;
```

In other words, *do not add a predicate that would fail in this case*, or you will lose the ability to report sane error messages. Instead, use a language-specific listener or visitor implementation after the parse is complete to report a *semantic* error if the type of the default value does not match the declared type.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently running the listener via a `ParseTreeWalker` and throwing `ParseCancellationException` when things look odd. I've looked at using `Parser.addParseListener()` for less-predictable "live" listening, but I'm guessing in this case there's no need for early detection or intervention.